# Issue with Geocoding Address on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

Hello I have the following array of address's

```
var Address= [
    { "Key": "1", "Title": "Candidate A", "Line1": "26 Dove Ave", "line2": "", "suburb": "Altona", "state": "VIC", "postcode": "3018" },
    { "Key": "2", "Title": "Candidate B", "Line1": "101 Collins Street", "line2": "", "suburb": "Melbourne", "state": "VIC", "postcode": "3000" },
    { "Key": "3", "Title": "Candidate C", "Line1": "15 Elgin St", "line2": "", "suburb": "Carlton", "state": "VIC", "postcode": "3053" },
    { "Key": "4", "Title": "Candidate D", "Line1": "435 Bridge Road", "line2": "", "suburb": "Richmond", "state": "VIC", "postcode": "3121" }
];
```

I then call geocoder whilst looping through the above array as follows

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address[i].Line1 + " , " + address[i].suburb },
```

But the markers on the map are not correct, for example the first entry in the array shows on the map as Swallow Street, Altona VIC 3018, Australia I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I've tried switching the suburb to postcode but the result is always the same??!

** Added the below code showing the complete process

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': Address[i].Line1 + " , " + Address[i].suburb },

    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
                map: map
            });

            //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function () { // Click event for each location to show the description
            //    return function () {
            //       GetDirections(results[0].geometry.location.lat() + "," + results[0].geometry.location.lng(), address);
            //    };
            //})(marker, i));

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {

                var latLng = e.latLng.k + "," + e.latLng.A;

                console.log(e);

                GetDirections(latLng);

            });

            markers.push(marker);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("text_status").value = status;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show the code that creates the markers

Comment: what about results, how you are pushing the values?

Comment: That's what I get for *26 Dove Ave,Altona* , seems to be correct: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3D26%20Dove%20Ave%2CAltona

Comment: @Dr.Molle When I do a direction request (once clicking on the marker it says start address:  Swallow Street, Altona VIC 3018, Australia

Comment: You may have noticed that the marker for the geocoding(see my link) is not placed on a street. Assuming that you use the travelMode `DRIVING`,  google has to find a point on a street near the given LatLng(the name of the street doesn't matter here, the LatLng is relevant)